# Even after fetching float value from Firebase, Toast displays value null

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

```
DatabaseReference dr1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
    dr1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                if(userID.equals(ds.child("userIDOriginal").getValue().toString()))
                {
                    monthlyBudget = Float.parseFloat(ds.child("userMonthlyBudget").getValue().toString());
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+monthlyBudget,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This is code fetching float value from firebase database,Toast shows correct value when placed inside, but shows null value when placed outside the ValueEventListener.Can anyone suggest solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is working exactly as I would expect, since Firebase listeners are asynchronous.

Comment: Yes even I am expecting the output but unfortunately it's still displaying null value

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see why do you have this behavior and how can you solve this using a custom callback.